# Is it possible to overcook peas?

Tags: cooking-time, overcooking

Is it possible to overcook peas as one could overcook a steak or pasta, or are they like mushrooms in that they cannot be overcooked?

Comment: Fresh green peas or dried peas?

Comment: If you try, you can overcook anything.

Comment: @SnakeDoc with fresh peas, you don't even have to try. Look at them wrong and they turn brown and unappealing.

Comment: @SnakeDoc mushrooms are kind of difficult to, unless you get them either soggy or burn them :)

Answer (score 6):

Yes! Fresh/frozen green peas can really easily be overcooked. They'll lose the bright green, getting more dull and a bit darker. They'll also get mushy. If you've had both nicely cooked fresh/frozen peas and canned peas, this should be pretty familiar to you.

If you mean something dried, more like beans, then sure, you can still overcook. The color is already a bit of a lost cause, but they'll still get mushy with extended cooking.

Comment: Yes. Canned peas are a good example of this.

Comment: So many think that mushy is cooked correctly while others of us consider that ruined.  Is a matter of taste and experience I suppose though.

Comment: @dlb Well, even if you like mushy, it's possible to cook them til they disintegrate. So unless your goal is something like mashed pea soup, they can still be overcooked.